# ksh cannot cp from location with space in it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, ksh

I am trying to do the following in `ksh` but keep getting `cannot stat` message for the `cp` command:

```
JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation

SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/*.*

cp $SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION /var/tmp/tempor
```

Any ideas? I have tried putting quotes around the various variables but with no luck.

Comment: Note the `*.*`. I don't know enough of the Korn shell, but in Bash, this would require arrays: `SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=("$JMX_ROOT/Smoke Set"/*.*)` followed by `cp "${SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION[@]}" /var/tmp/tempor`.

Comment: also exists on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7916105/7552)

Answer (score 1):

```
cp "$SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION" /var/tmp/tempor
#--^-------------------^
```

EDIT: I didn't really notice the wildcards. Yes, quoting them will prevent expansion.  Is there any reason you need to put them in a variable? Surely this would work:

```
cp $JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/*.* /var/tmp/tempor
```

Comment: Could you expand on "wouldn't work"? Copy-paste your commands and error messages, please.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work as is, so changed it to the following..

    SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/Smoke*/*.*

I.e. used a wildcard instread of including the space

Comment: @Rory, what he gave you is the correct solution (in the edit part at least), youre doing something else wrong, but we cant help unless you give us your commands and errors as requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION="$(echo $JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/*.*)"
cp "$SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION" /var/tmp/tempor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate field separator to work around that white space in the directory name.

```
JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation

OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION="${JMX_ROOT}/Smoke Set"

cp ${SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION}/*.* /var/tmp/tempor

IFS=$OLD_IFS
```